# How to make this boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot graph in R with ggplot2 like the one seen in the example figures. In the "x" axis, the data of the boxplot would correspond in this case of NDVI of plant cover and in the "y" axis, the correlation values ​​between the NDVI and another variable. So far, you can only create the boxplot graph that shows the NDVI values ​​on the "y" axis. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Add sample of my data, LANDUSE contains 3 types of vegetation cover: WETL, SHRU and BARR. NDVI are the NDVI values ​​for each cover and R2 the correlation of the NDVI values ​​with other data (soil moisture), in total I only have three R2 data, each for the three types of plant cover.

```
 LANDUSE    NDVI    R2
1   WETL    0.41490  0.71
2   WETL    0.35825  0.71
3   WETL    0.48040  0.71
4   WETL    0.46865  0.71
5   WETL    0.40155  0.71
6   WETL    0.32255  0.71
7   WETL    0.29695  0.71
8   WETL    0.27215  0.71
9   WETL    0.27560  0.71
10  WETL    0.25590  0.71
11  WETL    0.26100  0.71
12  WETL    0.25795  0.71
13  WETL    0.28835  0.71
14  WETL    0.41735  0.71
15  WETL    0.44215  0.71
16  WETL    0.48855  0.71
17  WETL    0.39070  0.71
18  WETL    0.31940  0.71
19  WETL    0.27780  0.71
20  WETL    0.25895  0.71
21  WETL    0.29435  0.71
22  WETL    0.29510  0.71
23  WETL    0.27760  0.71
24  WETL    0.29510  0.71
25  WETL    0.36605  0.71
26  WETL    0.40170  0.71
27  WETL    0.47175  0.71
28  WETL    0.47125  0.71
29  WETL    0.38540  0.71
30  SHRB    0.40545  0.78
31  SHRB    0.35295  0.78
32  SHRB    0.44720  0.78
33  SHRB    0.39525  0.78
34  SHRB    0.33565  0.78
35  SHRB    0.26720  0.78
36  SHRB    0.24750  0.78
37  SHRB    0.22590  0.78
38  SHRB    0.22220  0.78
39  SHRB    0.20930  0.78
40  SHRB    0.21205  0.78
41  SHRB    0.22265  0.78
42  SHRB    0.26165  0.78
43  SHRB    0.40230  0.78
44  SHRB    0.42050  0.78
45  SHRB    0.42760  0.78
46  SHRB    0.32310  0.78
47  SHRB    0.27360  0.78
48  SHRB    0.23945  0.78
49  SHRB    0.23050  0.78
50  SHRB    0.23655  0.78
51  SHRB    0.22880  0.78
52  SHRB    0.21850  0.78
53  SHRB    0.24015  0.78
54  SHRB    0.29850  0.78
55  SHRB    0.35620  0.78
56  SHRB    0.43130  0.78
57  SHRB    0.41165  0.78
58  SHRB    0.31965  0.78
59  SHRB    0.25735  0.78
60  BARR    0.19040  0.54
61  BARR    0.18645  0.54
62  BARR    0.24925  0.54
63  BARR    0.24545  0.54
64  BARR    0.21630  0.54
65  BARR    0.18645  0.54
66  BARR    0.17610  0.54
67  BARR    0.16485  0.54
68  BARR    0.16450  0.54
69  BARR    0.15730  0.54
70  BARR    0.16140  0.54
71  BARR    0.14540  0.54
72  BARR    0.15485  0.54
73  BARR    0.21290  0.54
74  BARR    0.24940  0.54
75  BARR    0.26325  0.54
76  BARR    0.20705  0.54
77  BARR    0.17210  0.54
78  BARR    0.13090  0.54
79  BARR    0.13335  0.54
80  BARR    0.17345  0.54
81  BARR    0.17155  0.54
82  BARR    0.16610  0.54
83  BARR    0.19005  0.54
84  BARR    0.20255  0.54
85  BARR    0.19690  0.54
86  BARR    0.25600  0.54
87  BARR    0.24950  0.54
88  BARR    0.20705  0.54
89  BARR    0.17955  0.54
Showing 1 to 15 of 89 entries, 3 total columns
```

Comment: What code did you try exactly? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This: ggplot(data = NDVI, aes(x= LANDUSE, y= NDVI, fill= LANDUSE)) + stat_boxplot() + geom_boxplot()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I am not sure about your `y` var but I used `NDVI`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=LANDUSE,y=NDVI,group=factor(R2)))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

**Update**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=LANDUSE,y=NDVI,fill=R2))+
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks duck, I have the same result. The problem is that I need to include the variable R2 in the "y" axis. It is like having two charts in one. The idea is that the three resulting box plots of y = NDVI (BARR, SHRB and WETL) vary on the "y" axis according to R2, in this case for BARR it is 0.54, SHRB is 0.78 and WETL is 0.71; therefore, the BARR boxplot should be below the others because it has a lower value of R2.

Comment: @AngelaMilagrosFigueroaTapia you could fill and colour by `R2`.

Comment: @AngelaMilagrosFigueroaTapia I have updated using `R2` to fill each box and see another scale.